# objective c how create new playlist on SoundCloud?

Tags: objective-c, rest, soundcloud

Trying to create new playlist, but it doesn't work.

> Function for request:

```
-(NSURLRequest *)makeNewPlaylistsRequestNamed:(NSString *)name
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.soundcloud.com/playlists"];
    NSURLComponents *comp = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:url
                                       resolvingAgainstBaseURL:YES];

    NSMutableArray *qi = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [qi addObject:[NSURLQueryItem queryItemWithName:@"oauth_token" value:self.authResult.value]];
    comp.queryItems = qi;

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:comp.URL];
    request.HTTPMethod = @"PUT";

    NSDictionary *newPL = @{@"title":name,@"sharing":@"public",@"tracks":@[]};
    NSDictionary *gistDict = @{@"playlist":newPL};

    NSError *jsonError;
    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:gistDict
                                                       options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                         error:&jsonError];

    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

    return request;
}
```

But new playlist doesn't creates. 
I used web API - https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#playlists

Comment: could add some more info of what isn't working?

Comment: After sending the request, the new playlist should appear, but it does not happen

Comment: NSURLSession returns response with status "Status = "404 Not Found""